# IE8 shows Bootstrap mobile nav while loading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one irritating issue.
During loading, IE8 shows Bootstrap's mobile menu (stretched 100%-fullwidth) for a part of second, and after that "normal" menu is shown.
Very very irritating issue.

Header looks like this:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <TITLE>Title</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<META NAME="description" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="author" CONTENT="GlobalCAD">
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir">

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I really dont have a clue what could be the reason, anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you use respond.js also. So load respond.js before ie8-and-down.css may fix your irritating issue

Comment: Yep, i do use it, will try to add it before the IE related stylesheet and will see what happens.Thanks